Searching for collibra API to get the "description of asset"
I want to get the the "description of the asset" through API from Collibra . I have searched but didn't get anything and also gone through API documentation. Please help me out on this.
Need collibra API to fetch "description of asset" and display on my own application.

To retrieve and process attributes of assets using the /rest/2.0/attributes API, follow these steps:

API Endpoint
Access the /rest/2.0/attributes API endpoint 1. You can find more details at the API documentation 1.

Filter by assetId
Specify your query to filter attributes by assetId. This will narrow down the search to attributes related to a specific asset.

Post-process the Results
Once you receive the API response, post-process the results within your application. Filter the attributes to identify those whose type is 'Definition'.

Extract the Definition
From the filtered attributes, extract the value of the attribute which represents the definition of your asset.


Here is an example of the JSON response you might receive from this API call:
{
  "total": 1,
  "offset": 0,
  "limit": 1000,
  "results": [
    {
      "id": "018f818c-df39-78a2-bea3-a3ccea687e85",
      "createdBy": "018ebc9b-56bd-2f12-a267-59eedef61804",
      "createdOn": 1515865444153,
      "lastModifiedBy": "018ebcob-56bd-7f12-a267-59eedef61804",
      "lastModifiedOn": 1225865244154,
      "system": false,
      "resourceType": "StringAttribute",
      "type": {
        "id": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000102",
        "resourceType": "StringAttributeType",
        "name": "Definition"
       },
       "asset": {
         "id": "018f818a-aa82-9fcc-ae37-308430e180e7",
         "resourceType": "Asset",
         "name": "First Name"
       },
       "value": "<div><div>First Name: A person's given name, usually appearing before the family name or surname, used to address or identify someone in a business setting.</div></div><p> </p>"
    }
  ]
}


Make sure to replace YOUR-DOMAIN with the actual domain of your API
service in the reference links.

